# Mount host directory in a virtual machine

Tags: mount, directory, virtual-machine

I have a directory on a system which is the host for a virtual machine. I want to make this directory accessible from the guest of the virtual machine.

There are some way I can think of, packing the directory to iso or img file which means make a copy of the directory, not the directory itself. For virtualbox, there's shared folder method which I have to install guest additions to the guest machine. That's not what I need because I want to mount the directory when installing Arch Linux on a new virtual machine.

I can't find a way for Qemu too. Then I wondering, is it even possible? If it is, how to do that?

My goal is to do something like:

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

inside the guest machine, but instead of `/dev/sdb`, somehow pass a directory of the host machine.

More specifically, I've backed up all of packages that `pacman` has downloaded to a directory in host machine. And I want to mount that directory to `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` so I don't need to download the package everytime I install Arch Linux. I'm doing Arch installations often for testing purposes.

Comment: This is very unclear (to me). What are you actually trying to do? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @roaima Updated. That's the specific goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done by using NFS. You'll have to install a NSF server on your host (very easy) and then mount the directory on the guest. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS